# PHP get MongoDBRef with query

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I was wondering if there is a way to perform a find() and have Mongo automatically return the associated references without having to run getDBRef() once the parent record has been returned.

I don't see it anywhere in the PHP documentation. I can easily support using getDBRef but it doesn't seem as efficient as it could be.

Also...I'm surprised there's no way to select the specific data to return in the linked reference. I may as well just perform another manual find statement so I can control what the return is...but there *has* to be a more performance oriented way to do this.

Perhaps I should change my methodology and instead of using the PHP library classes for find, generate my own JavaScript command and run it using the MongoCode class? Would that work and if so...I'm wondering what it would look like. *scratches head then heads to The Google*

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB does not support joins.  [Database References (DBRefs)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/) just refers to the practice of a field storing an `_id` referencing another document.   There is currently no specific server-side support for this, and hydrating the reference to a document **does** require another  query.  Some [MongoDB drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) have convenience methods so you don't have to manually do the find.  It is equally valid/performant if you want to do your own `find()` given a DBRef to lookup (or use other criteria to find related documents).

Depending on your use case and data modelling, a more efficient alternative to the DBRef linking could be embedding related data as a subdocument.  See the MongoDB wiki info on [Schema Design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design) for more examples.

As far as performance goes, it would be better to use PHP queries than [MongoCode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocode.php) (JavaScript which needs to be eval'ed on the server).  MongoCode is really intended for more limited use such as within Map/Reduce functions.  Refer to [Server-Side Code Execution](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Limitationsof%7B%7Beval%7D%7D) for some of the potential limitations with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Refer: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/

**Manual references** where you save the _id field of one document in another document as a reference. Then your application can run a second query to return the related data. These references are simple and sufficient for most use cases.

**DBRefs** are references from one document to another using the value of the first document’s _id field, collection name, and, optionally, its database name. By including these names, DBRefs allow documents located in multiple collections to be more easily linked with documents from a single collection.

To resolve DBRefs, your application must perform additional queries to return the referenced documents. Many drivers have helper methods that form the query for the DBRef automatically. **The drivers do not automatically resolve DBRefs into documents.**

So either way, no matter which type of referencing you are using, you need to do the dereferencing yourself.

Hope it helps!